# Accessing Javascript variable Value in another javascript file / Html file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a js file and a html file:

jScript1.js

```
var a = 0.05 ;
var var1 = a;
function myFunc1(){
    console.log("original"+ a);
    a = a*5 ;
    console.log("processed a"+ a) ;
    var1 = a;
}
```

index.html

```
<body>
<script src="jScript1.js">myFunc1();</script>

<script>

console.log("display"+ a);
</script>

</body>
```

I am able to access var1 in js file but when I use it, I get the initialization value [in this case 0.05] and not the processed value which is stored in var1 after calling myFunc() in the script tag with js file as script resource

How to get the final value of var1 in the html file after the processing that is happening inside myFunc()?

Comment: Where is `myFunc()` called from, and *when*? (Any async code here?)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "including the script"? Why are you using global variables? You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @nnnnnn myFunc is defined and called in Java1.js and results in a change in the value of var1 which I can print on console in Java1.js

Comment: But, again, *when* is it called, and is there any asynchronous code involved? If it's all synchronous then what you've described should work. (As an aside, calling the files Java1 and Java2 is a bit misleading when Java and JavaScript are unrelated languages.)

Comment: Thanks for your response & suggestions. Let me edit the question. Apologies for inconvenience. @nnnnnn

Comment: It would help if you could include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Relevant excerpts from the specification (I took them from https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-script-element.html in particular):

> When used to include dynamic scripts, the scripts may either be embedded inline or may be imported from an external file using the src attribute.
>   [...]
>   (Step 15.)
>   [...]
>   **If the element has a src attribute**
>   The element must be added to the set of scripts that will execute as soon as possible of the Document of the script element at the time the prepare a script algorithm started. [...]
>
> **Otherwise**
>   The user agent must immediately execute the script block, even if other scripts are already executing.

I am not sure how it has gone unnoticed, but that `myFunc1();` call simply does not get executed, and its logs do not appear at all.
If you try

```
<body>
  <script src="jScript1.js"></script>

  <script>
    console.log("display1 " + a);
    myFunc1();
    console.log("display2 " + a);
  </script>
</body>
```

instead, that will work.

(While the notation 'dynamic script' may seem a bit confusing, the alternative is 'data block')

Comment: I understood what you said, the myFunc1() wasn't executed. I am trying to do something similar with a serial port and electron and am facing issues.

Comment: @U7786 users only see what you write. If you need advice, you should describe the actual issue you are facing.